# Botão de Clique/Reset

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='liveExample'> 

    <div><span data-bind='text: numberOfClicks'>&nbsp;</span></div>

      <div data-bind='visible: hasClickedTooManyTimes'>
        <button data-bind='click: resetClicks'>Reset clicks</button>
    </div>

    <button data-bind='click: registerClick, disable: hasClickedTooManyTimes'>Click me</button>


</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ClickCounterViewModel = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);

    this.registerClick = function() {
        this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + 1);
    };

    this.resetClicks = function() {
        this.numberOfClicks(0);
    };

    this.hasClickedTooManyTimes = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.numberOfClicks() >= 99;
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());
```

Que faz com eu tenha um botão (Click Me) em que sempre que lhe dou um click, o número altera ascendentemente (do 1 ao 99). Sempre que chega ao 99, aparece-me um outro botão (Reset Me) que faz com que a contagem volte ao início. - isto faz com que seja necessário ter dois botões.

O que eu gostaria de entender era: é possível colocar tudo num só botão? Acredito que seja uma função JavaScript que desconheço.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ClauKMS, evite colocar captura de telas do código. Edite sua pergunta e coloque o seu código!

Comment: Obrigada Luiz, já alterei. Consegues ajudar-me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que você quer é que o mesmo botão que incrementa, ao chegar no 99° click ele mesmo reseta e volta a contar do início, poderia fazer o seguinte, na função registerClick coloca para ele verificar se atingiu o valor máximo, se atingir reseta.
Ficaria assim o código:

**HTML**

```
<div class='liveExample'> 
<button data-bind='click: registerClick'>Click me</button>  
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ClickCounterViewModel = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);

    this.registerClick = function() {
        if(this.numberOfClicks() >= 99){
            alert('Atingiu o limite, vamos resetar');
            this.resetClicks();
        }else{
            this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + 1);
        }
    };

    this.resetClicks = function() {
        this.numberOfClicks(0);
    };

    this.hasClickedTooManyTimes = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.numberOfClicks() >= 99;
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: I'm glad i can help you! If this answer helps you, please consider mark it as correct one.